# Browser tab title is "Loading" while opening a subtab

Tags: lightning

I am using `workspaceAPI` to open a subtab from a parent tab. I am using `setTabLabel` to set the subtab label, but I have noticed the browser tab displayed as "Loading". 
Any suggestion?

```
 workspaceAPI
            .isConsoleNavigation()
            .then(function(isConsole) {
                if (isConsole) {
                    navService.generateUrl(pageReference).then(function(cmpURL) {
                        workspaceAPI
                        .getEnclosingTabId()
                        .then(function(tabId) {
                             return workspaceAPI.openSubtab({                            
                                parentTabId: tabId,
                                url: cmpURL,
                                focus: true
                            });                        
                        })
                        .then(function(subTabId) {                            
                            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                                tabId: subTabId,
                                label: "Debt Accounts"
                            });

                            workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                                tabId: subTabId, 
                                icon: "standard:knowledge",
                                iconAlt: "Debt Account"
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Browser tab `name/title` depends on `focused tab/subtab label`.

Even though I was setting the `subtab` as a `focused` tab but still browser title was still showing as "**Loading...**".

so, in the script, I have added 2 new lines to set the focused tab the parent tab and again `focused` it back to the `subtab`.

```
workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : enclosingTabId});
workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : subtabId});
```

**Entire script:**

```
workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(enclosingTabId) {
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
                pageReference: {
                    type: "standard__component",
                    attributes: {
                        "componentName": "c__CustomComponent"
                    },
                    state: {
                        c__param1: recId,
                        c__param2: objName
                    }
                },
                focus: true
            }).then(function(subtabId) {
                // the subtab has been created, use the Id to set the label
                workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                    tabId: subtabId,
                    label: "SubTab Label Name"
                });

                // the subtab has been created, use the Id to set the icon
                workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                    tabId: subtabId, 
                    icon: "standard:knowledge",
                    iconAlt: "SubTab Label Name"
                });
                workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : enclosingTabId});
                workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : subtabId});                                
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("error");
            });
        });
```